# Laravel multiple object instantiation

Tags: php, oop, laravel

I'm fairly new to Laravel and was wondering what the most efficient way of instantiating and making available multiple objects to my classes was.

An example of what I am doing currently would be, in kind of sudo code:

// MainController.php

```
<?php

Class MainController extends BaseController {

     public function __construct() {
          parent::construct();         
     }

     // class code follows
}
```

// BaseContoller.php

```
<?php

use classFile;
Use repositoryFile;
use classFile2;
Use repositoryFile2;

..... and lets say 10 more "included" files

Class BaseController extends Controller {

     var classFile;
     var repositoryFile;
     var classFile2;
     var repositoryFile2;

     ..... and 10 more variables;

     public function __construct() {

           $this->classFile = new classFile;      
           $this->classFile = new classFile;
           $this->repositoryFile = new repositoryFile;
           $this->classFile2 = new classFile2;
           $this->repositoryFile2 = new repositoryFile2;

           ..... and 10 more class instantiations

      }

      // class code follows

}
```

Hopefully that makes sense.....

Almost all of my classes that inherit BaseController will at some point make use of these objects so loading them all in for each class is I guess the right thing. My main two questions though are:

1. How expensive, from a pure code point of view, is instantiating multiple objects like this before they are needed. I have included them in the BaseController file because I found myself repeating these included definitions in the numerous files that inherit from BaseController.
2. From a Laravel point of view is there a better framework way of doing this kind of thing? Originally I had them being injected in through each classes constructor but again they were being repeated (the same definition in multiple files) and were becoming horribly large.

I've followed a lot of the Laracasts tuts as well as various reading material but I've not yet seen how people handle a large volume of objects like I'm trying to use. Or perhaps thats where I'm going "wrong"?

Cheers !

== Heres an example of the call for the homepage of the API I'm working on. It aggregates content from all across the site into a feed for a mobile app:

```
    public function index()
{
    $channels = $this->channelRepository->getChannels();
    $allChannels = $this->channelRepository->getAllChannels();
    $sponsors = $this->sponsorRepository->getSponsors();
    $inactiveUserChannels = [];

    // use the pattern maker, set the pattern we want to use
    $this->patternMaker->setPattern(1);

    $channelFeed = [];

    if( userIsAuthenticated() )
    {
        $inactiveUserChannels = $this->userRepository->getUserInactiveChannels( 1 );    
    }        

    // Picks
    $picks = $this->articleRepository->getArticles( 'picks', 25 );

    $ads = $this->sponsorRepository->getWhereNotInCollection( $sponsors, 30 );
    $response = $this->patternMaker->make( [ 'articles' => $picks, 'sponsors' => $ads ] );
    $picks = $response->articles;
    $ads = $response->sponsors;

    // Whats on
    $channel = 50;

    $whatsOn = $this->articleRepository->getArticlesWithEvents(null); // get 20 articles from the whats on channel
    $response = $this->patternMaker->make( [ 'articles' => $whatsOn, 'sponsors' => $ads ], "whats-on" );
    $whatsOn = $response->articles;

    $ads = $response->sponsors;

    $channel = $this->channelTransformer->transform( getChannel($channels, $channel) );
    $channel['articles'] = $whatsOn;

    $channelFeed[] = $channel;

    // create a new instance of the channel feed class and pass the required params to it

    $this->channelFeed = $this->createChannelFeed( $allChannels, [ 48, 49, 51, 52 ], $ads, $inactiveUserChannels );

    if( ! $response = cached("homepage") )
    {
        $data = [
            'channels' => $this->channelTransformer->transformCollection( $channels )
            ,'adverts' => $this->sponsorTransformer->transformCollection( $sponsors->toArray() )
            ,'features' => $this->articleTransformer->transformCollection( $this->articleRepository->getArticles( 'featured', 25 ), [ 'showBody' => false] )
            ,'picks' => $picks
            ,'channelFeed' => $this->channelFeed->make()
        ];

        cacheIt("homepage", $response, "1 hour");
    }

    return $this->respondFound(Lang::get('api.homepageFound'), $data);
}
```

This is early stage and I am refactoring as I go which is where this question of class dependencies has come from.

Comment: Read and use this: http://laravel.com/docs/ioc

Comment: @Sergiu Using IoC, all the 10+ classes would be instantiated each time BaseController (or its children) is constructed still, no?

Comment: Ah my bad, using `App::singleton()` and returning a factory could work I guess

Comment: Would you mind providing more of a "real-world-example"? Your code indicates a bit of a code smell (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). 14 dependencies in a single controller is probably not how you want to go through it.

Comment: I have a basic understanding of Laravels IOC container (i think)... Correct me if I'm wrong - binding the classes I require throughout the app (an API in this case) and then automatically resolving them through the constructor would still mean that I need to type hint and create each of the 10 (example) objects, as per the example given in the Laravel docs, for each class that needs to make use of them right?  (which is actually how I started out before I moved them to the BaseController class)

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat - I'll try and pull something out of what I'm working on. This is actually for an API that grabs lots of data from multiple areas of a site (for a homepage, so different types of content)

Comment: So how is it different than most other languages that support IoC and automatic dependency injection based on typehints?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Im not suggesting its different. I'm asking if my understanding is correct? To me having all of these type hints seemed....untidy. I was wondering if there was a better or cleaner way thats all.

Comment: Having so many dependencies possibly denotes wrong application architecture. It does not mean though the tools are wrong.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Thanks. I'm in no way implying anything negative about the framework (its awesome). Just trying to get a better understanding off the cleanest way to approach something that does rely on a number of different aspects of the application for data aggregation.

Comment: And we get that. What you need to do is think about how you can couple all those dependencies into modules and _depend_ on those to abstract the more granular logic you seem to use in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

First, unless your constructor on the MainController have more logic you can just leave out the constructor all together and the BaseController constructor will be called directly.

You could do this:

```
 Class BaseController extends Controller {

      protected $classFile;
      //repeat for all classes

      function classFile() {
           if(!$this->classFile) $this->clasFile = new classFile;
           return $this->classFile;
      }
      //repeat for all classes

      function useExample() {
           $this->classFile()->randomMethod();
      }  

 }
```

... this way atleast you dont instanciate more than needed.

That beeing said, it sounds like what you really want is Facades, and you could just go:

```
$channels = ChannelRepository::getChannels();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/facades

Comment: I don't think making a controller act as a factory is a very good idea. You are also generating even more overhead this way than it currently is.

Comment: @fiffen Thanks. I'm making use of facades throughout my app with my repositories and the like. What Im needing to do is pull a lot of data out of the DB, iterate over it to get what I need out of it, format it and return it in a pre-defined response object for a mobile app to ingest. I can't quite see how I would reduce the dependencies in this single controller action to achieve the same goal (hence my question). Good examples though, cheers.

Comment: You could write a class that receives a "query", pulls data using a service, maps it to a structure you need using a mapper, and returns it.

Comment: Thanks @SergiuParaschiv. Your comment about modules got me thinking and I think you've hit the nail on the head with your examples here. I've kind of done this to an extent with my transformers but still have way more logic in my controllers and far too many dependencies for that logic. Nice one.